# How to open a fragment to the user, just like a dialog?

Tags: android

I have a viewpager with fragments for slide. I would like the last fragment to appear to the user, just like a dialog. It is possible?

My viewpager below:

```
 //ViewPager inner class CondutasSlideActivity
    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 7;
        private ConsultaVo consultaVo1;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, ConsultaVo consultaVo) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.consultaVo1 = consultaVo;
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                    return FragmentAvaliacao.newInstance(consultaVo1);
                case 1: // Fragment # 1 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                    return FragmentReceita.newInstance(consultaVo1);
                case 2: // Fragment # 2 - This will show SecondFragment
                    return FragmentExames.newInstance(consultaVo1);
                case 3: // Fragment # 3 - This will show SecondFragment
                    return FragmentEncaminhamento.newInstance(consultaVo1);
                case 4: // Fragment # 4 - This will show SecondFragment
                    return FragmentOrientacoes.newInstance(consultaVo1);
                case 5: // Fragment # 5 - This will show SecondFragment
                    return FragmentAtestadoDeclaracao.newInstance(consultaVo1);
                case 6: // Fragment # 5 - This will show SecondFragment
                    return FinalizaConsultaFragment.newInstance(consultaVo1);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }

    }
```

Something like the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things which come in my mind at first.

- You have a `ViewPager` in your parent layout, you can set margin (like 40dp) so that all fragments have margin and get centered.
- You can wrap your `ViewPager` with `CardView` for this elevation and corners.

Comment: Only the last should be this way. I tried a cardview with elevation in the last fragment my background goes white, even `android:background =" @ android: color / transparent"`

Comment: Check your parent layouts, perhaps they have some background.

Comment: You can paste your layout code of here. I can then tell you some solution.